# Intellij issues with multiple source folders

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In our project, we are having two source folders, one source folder is for our application code(`src/main`) and another one is to generate JSON API schema(`src/schema`).

[image]

The functionalities are working fine because we are using `Gradle` to build and run the application, the only issue we are facing is: Intellij keeps showing compilation issues when we refer(`import`) a java class from the `src/main` folder in the `src/schema` folder like below:

[image]

where `UnsolicitedResponseProcessor.java` is a java class in the `src/schema` folder which is importing `Response.java` from the `src/main` folder.

So far, I have tried to mark the `src/schema` folder as `Source Directory` but this is not helping me.

Is there any way I can solve this IntelliJ's compilation issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add one sources root as a dependency for another in project settings -> modules

Comment: @KonstantinAnnikov this works but is changes would go off after re-starting the idea. Can we able to do this set-up in build.gradle file

Comment: Maybe Gradle multi-project can help you https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html